# Angular 2 session pattern implementation

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular 2 `SPA`. One of the patterns I use is to load a session object on `local storage` (requested back from the `API`) each time a user authenticates. This object contains data that all components need to access.

**Problem.** Information in the session object are loaded once in the beginning of session and are not updated unless the user `signout` and `signin` again (they are isolated from changes made by other users).

What is the best way to keep these information updated ?

***NB:*** Open to change this pattern to solve the problem by using a new approach to manage sessions

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular with MVC ..you can just load the mvc view and hand off to ng2 component...store the values of the session in a hidden field and read them in ng2 app..just a suggestion..have created a mvc app to load independent views..check it...https://github.com/chetankat007/angular2mvcrouting